# Github Action - Error: Process completed with exit code

Tags: node.js, npm, checkout, npm-scripts, npm-publish

I am trying to setup Github actions to npm publish my package. But I got this error When I move on execute

[image: Error: Process completed with exit code 1.]

My `workflows/publish.yml` file looks like the following:

```
name: publish

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
 

jobs:
  release:
    
    name: publish
    runs-on: windows-latest


    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4
    - name: Setup Node.js environment
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2.2.0
      with:
        node-version: 14
        registry-url : https://registry.nmpjs.org
    - name: publish
      run: npm publish --access public
      env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NODE_AUTH_TOKEN}}
```

[image]

Comment: The error most likely means that the file `package.json` does not exist. If it does, please share with us that file; otherwise, go to the directory and run `npm init` in the command line, follow the directions, and try again. It should work.

Comment: share your `package.json` file

Comment: @AmirSaleem here is my `package.json` file ( https://gist.github.com/c5ee85ede67d6f605f99f674a4665494.git )

Comment: It seems the syntax of your package.json is incorrect. How did you create it?

Comment: it's not a complete file. The package json must be a valid json. a json has curly braces in start and end. Your package json file is broken

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I create it by using the command prompt. i just added the JSON file, not all files are including that link, and also know that there are a few changes but my concern is different than where is wrong to publish my package by using GitHub. action.

Comment: @AmirSaleem i just added the error that I get right now.  after following your instruction.

Comment: ok checking the error

Comment: @MohammadSakibMahmood Your `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN ` must have appropriate access in order to publish. Verify this.

Comment: This might help: https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-your-registry-settings-as-an-npm-enterprise-user

Comment: @MohammadSakibMahmood if you are using npm registry, you need an `.npmrc` file with correct token and username. Alternatively you can use github registry by replacing the `registry-url` with `registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package.json file is broken.

```js
{
  "name": "@sakibb019/npx-card",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "card.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon card.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "repository": {
    "url": "git://github.com/sakibb019/test.git"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "boxen": "^5.0.1",
    "chalk": "^4.1.1",
    "clear": "^0.1.0",
    "inquirer": "^8.1.0"
  }
}
```

I've added the missing braces, still, you would need to find a complete package JSON file. There should be more content after `"inquirer": "^8.1.`

Comment: Thanks for informing me. i just feel gotta dump that i missed the braces in my `json file` . I correct that following your instruction but still I got same the error from it.

Comment: share your updated JSON file and the error you are getting.

Comment: you can use an online tool like https://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON

Comment: i checked my json file by using jsonlint.com which shows valid json as a result but I got that error when I check my Github action which I already post on my question asked.

Comment: the error is exactly the same as posted in your question?

Comment: yes, i checked it again and again and i was correct a little bit correction on it. that I give in the link (https://gist.github.com/c5ee85ede67d6f605f99f674a4665494.git)

Comment: make sure you are not using sort of cache in your GitHub actions

Comment: yes, i just checked that no cache I'm using for. and the result is no